# How to Prevent content displayed above the safe area when scrolled in iOS app build using capacitor?

Tags: ios, angular, capacitor

I am building a mobile app from my angular project using capacitor without ionic.
Since the app goes to full screen in iPhone the app overlaps the status barto fix that I have configured  in capacitor.config.json as
"ios": {
"contentInset": "automatic"
}

After adding the contentInset: automatic my layout is properly laid.
But when i scroll up the scrolled content is displayed in the status bar since iphone have transparent status bar.
Is there any way to hide the scrolled content in status bar while scrolling?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Capacitor 5, you can use the `contentInset` property set to `always` in the iOS settings in capacitor.config.json:

```
"ios": {
    "contentInset": "always"
},
```

I found you also have to use `100dvh` and `100dvw` in the CSS to make sure you get heights and widths within those bounds.

Answer (score -1):

you need to set:

`scrollView.clipToBounds = true`

Comment: I am converting my angular project to ios app using capacitor.

Comment: try to change `{ "contentInset": "automatic" }` ->  `{ "contentInset": "automatic",  "clipToBounds" : true}` or  `{ "contentInset": "automatic",  "clipToBounds" : "true"}`

Comment: Just try, I think it works because contentInset is an attribute as same as clipToBounds

Comment: This answer is confusing, there is no attribute "clipToBounds" in a capacitor config file.